# My keyboard library for an esp32s2 is not working as it should

Tags: keyboard, ide, usb, arduino-esp32

The problem:
The keyboard script should type the text within a second. But it's typing slow, like a
human....

ps The program is printing text every 20sec

The board:
esp32s2

The code:

```
// Include Libraries
    #include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#include "USB.h"
#include "USBHIDKeyboard.h"
USBHIDKeyboard Keyboard;

void setup() {
  // Set up Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Keyboard.begin();
  USB.begin();
}

void loop() {

  delay(20000);
  Keyboard.println("kajdgjskajgklhjagkljakjgkl");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative: if you don't have to use "USBHIDKeyboard.h" specifically, consider "hidkeyboard.h" of *[ESP32TinyUSB](https://github.com/chegewara/EspTinyUSB)* library. It allows typing text very fast.

```
#include "hidkeyboard.h"
HIDkeyboard kbd;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  kbd.begin();
  //kbd.sendChar(66); // send ASCII char
  delay (3000);
  kbd.sendString("This is test \n");
}

void loop() {
  //kbd.sendChar(65); // send ASCII char
  kbd.sendString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \n");
  delay(3000);
}
```

Supproted typing functions of this library:

```
bool sendKey(uint8_t _keycode, uint8_t modifier = 0);
bool sendChar(uint8_t _keycode);
bool sendPress(uint8_t _keycode, uint8_t modifier = 0);
bool sendRelease();
bool sendString(const char* text);
bool sendString(String text);
```